# Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver

Tags: mysql, nhibernate

I used this code in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns= "urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>

    <!-- SQLServer: Provider --><!--
    <property name="connection.provider"> NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider </property>-->

      <!-- SQLServer: Driver -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class"> NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver </property>
    
    <!-- SQLServer: Dialeto -->
    <property name="dialect"> NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect </property>
    
    <!-- SQLServer: Connection String -->
    <property name="connection.connection_string"> Database=nhibernate;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=xxxx</property>
    
    <!-- Classe que será utilizada para Proxy
       (LazyLoading) -->
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class"> NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu </property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have a problem creating the database.

> NHibernate.HibernateException: Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> NHibernate.HibernateException: The IDbCommand and IDbConnection implementation in the assembly MySql.Data could not be found. ...

What should I do?

Comment: Not solve your problem but searching on internet I think it is useful.
Be sure of the CASE of the driver name (Sql instead SQL):
CORRECT: NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver
INCORRECT: NHibernate.Driver.MySQLDataDriver

Answer (score 30):

It's simple: add Mysql.Data.dll to the project's bin folder.

Comment: As a side note: if this solution doesn't work, make a right click on the `MySql.Data` in the references and set the option `Copy Local` to `True`

Comment: I should also add that it needs to be added to the main web app project (or the project that actually runs) rather then just to a standard library project containing your data access code.

Comment: Copy Local does not necessarily work. With MSTest, I had to copy it from the package folder into the bin folder of the test project. (Visual Studio 2013 SP1 RC)